# validating the form with same input field names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below jquery code to validate the form.

```
function validateForm(){


        $("input.field1").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Required"
            }
        } );            
    });



    $("input.fieldTwo").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 12,
            email: true
            messages: {
                required: "Enter email",
                email: "Enter valid email",
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });



    $("input.field3").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: false,
            maxlength: 12
            messages: {
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });

    $("input.field4").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: false,
            maxlength: 12
            messages: {
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });

    $("input.field5").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: false,
            maxlength: 12
            messages: {
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });



        return $("#myForm").validate({
          onfocusout: function(element) { jQuery(element).valid(); } 
    });

  }
```

But it always gives script error saying `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`.

But i believe no where } is required.

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing commas... Is this really the place? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a type-error 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing several commas.  See code, and replicate throughout.

```
$("input.fieldTwo").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 12,
        email: true  //MISSING COMMA
        messages: {
            required: "Enter email",
            email: "Enter valid email",
            maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
        }
    } );            
});

$("input.field3").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: false,
        maxlength: 12  //MISSING COMMA
        messages: {
            maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
        }
    } );            
});

$("input.field4").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: false,
        maxlength: 12  //MISSING COMMA
        messages: {
            maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
        }
    } );            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma here:

```
 $("input.field3").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: false,
            maxlength: 12, // added a comma here
            messages: {
                maxlength: "Maximum 12 characters"
            }
        } );            
    });
```

You've actually missed a comma in every single area after the `maxlength` property. Probably a copy and paste error?